# List size isnt working as expected for partner user

Tags: apex, query, list

I have observed very weired nature in Lists result.

I run this query in query editor:

```
select id, Title, Description, FileType,FeaturedContentDate,FeaturedContentBoost,ContentDocumentId,TagCsv
from  ContentVersion
where FeaturedContentDate!=null and FeaturedContentBoost!=null
Order By CreatedDate Desc
```

**I got 2 records.**

I used same query in Apex: for sfdc user- 2 records,partner users-87 records

I received very shocking result for partner users:

```
system.debug('before content list-->'+contentList); //zero
for(ContentVersion cont:[
    select id, Title, Description, FileType,FeaturedContentDate,FeaturedContentBoost,ContentDocumentId,TagCsv
    from  ContentVersion
    where FeaturedContentDate!=null and FeaturedContentBoost!=null
    Order By CreatedDate Desc]
    ){
    contentList.add(cont);    
}
system.debug('--contentList size()--->'+contentList.size()); //87
```

**I received 87 records.**

How its possible?

- I logged in as partner user & tried this logic works in sandbox (its working as expected) & moving the code to another sandbox,while doing the testing I rec ivied above result.

**I have used withsharing also.but I can see same result**

for testing purpose:

```
public class testContent {
public static void test(){
    List<ContentVersion>contentList1=[select id, Title, Description, FileType,FeaturedContentDate,FeaturedContentBoost,ContentDocumentId,TagCsv from  ContentVersion
                                      where FeaturedContentDate!=null and FeaturedContentBoost!=null  Order By CreatedDate Desc];
    system.debug('----contentList1----'+contentList1.size());
}

}
```

***for sfdc user i will getlist count is 2.for partner user result is 87***  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with sharing` and `without sharing` are "enough" to handle most sharing issues with regular sObjects, but sharing works differently on Content. Running a class `without sharing` *does not guarantee that the running user can see all Content*. It is normal and to be expected that different running users would be able to see different sets of Content.

Additionally, Anonymous Apex [runs in user context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_security_sharing_rules.htm), so comparing Anonymous Apex to Apex running in system mode is not an apples-to-apples comparison.

I would suggest reading through [Who Can See My File?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_settings_perms.htm&type=5), because the differences between Content sharing and regular sObject sharing are sometimes quite confusing - particularly when Files are shared on record pages.

It's particularly important to note that

> Users with “Modify All Data” permission can view, preview, download, share, attach, make private, restrict access, edit, upload new versions, and delete files they don't own. However, **if the file is in a private library, then only the file owner has access to it.**
>
> Users with “View All Data” permission can view and preview files they don't own. However, **if the file is in a private library, then only the file owner has access to it.**

Emphasis mine. This means that the normal System Administrator permissions to access everything in the system do not apply to Content, and there are situations where you will not be able to see Files owned by other users - even as a System Administrator. This *may* be the issue you are observing; it's certainly a common issue when trying to do broad-based queries against an org's Content.

If your test internal user is *not* a System Administrator, the number of situations where this user will be unable to see Content (regardless of sharing declaration) increases.

Overall, it will be hard to provide you with a more specific answer to your question without being in your org, because so many factors influence sharing and visibility. The first factors I would review to try to understand why each user sees what they see are:

- Who owns the files in question?
- What is the sharing setting, as described in Who Can See My File?, for these items?

> The sharing setting and icon appear on a file's detail page and on the Shared With list on a file detail page.

- Are the files in a library? Are they shared on record pages? What is the total sharing landscape?
- If the files are shared on record pages, who can see those records?
- What permissions and profiles are involved for both classes of users?

Spring '19 will provide a preview of a new [Query All Files permission](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_files_query_all_files.htm):

> With the new Query All Files permission, View All Data users can query ContentDocument and ContentVersion and retrieve all files in the org, including files in non-member libraries and files in unlisted groups. On its own, the View All Data permission only allows you to query files you own or have access to.

Answer (score 3):

this is because of that query editor, anonymous apex and standard controller enforce sharing rules. Meanwhile, without explicitly mentioning sharing keyword for apex class it runs in system mode. The new feature starting with `44.0` is [Inherited Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) is preferable to use

> An Apex class with inherited sharing runs as with sharing when used as
>   a Lightning component controller, a Visualforce controller, an Apex
>   REST service, or any other entry point to an Apex transaction.

---

Add `with sharing` to your apex class, where you perform SOQL and you will receive  2 records instead of 87